# For Windows 8.1, Does anyone have a way to get rid of the SecureBoot isn't configured correctly message?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

In my case, I actually did enable secure boot in the BIOS, and tried the factory reset of the BIOS, and nothing.  At this point I don't even care about "fixing" it by refreshing windows, I'd rather just have something that makes the message go away.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft released an Update to remove the message:

**Update removes the "Windows 8.1 SecureBoot isn't configured correctly" watermark in Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2902864/en-us

Download and install it.

Comment: Fair enough.  I guess we'll just have to hope for a Microsoft patch to deal with it some day.

Comment: @Mike_K MS released an update to remove it